# C#: Image unfolding to a rectangle

Tags: c#, image-processing, unfold

I need an advice in image processing. I have WF application coded in C# which finds me a coordinates by given parameters and based on this coordinates I would like to crop the image to a circle and unfold this circle to a rectangle.

So just to summarize my questions - How should I correctly crop the image in pictureBox to a circle (ellipse) image and how to unfold this circle to a rectangle?

I hope I described my problem well and I will be very grateful for every advice about how should I continue.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the image to be cropped to a circle and then have that circle expand to a rectangle?

This would be the way to do it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip.aspx
You then just animate the EllipseGeometry to make it bigger than the image and then maybe remove the clip if you like.

Comment: Yes, that's right - I want to crop the image to a circle and then expand this circle to a rectangle. Thank you for your tip!